# css-tricks.com media query just not working

Tags: css, media-queries

is there some new standard for using media queries. Or perhaps I should say, some new considerations that should be made.

The [CSS tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) doesn't seem to work very well, as the the 'smart phone landscape' seems to highjack everything.

code i've used taken direct (with the exception of printing what the screens supposedly are:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.size:after{ content: "smartphone portrait and landscape";}
body{background-color:#111; color:#fff;}
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
.size:after{ content: "smartphone landscape";}
body{background-color:#222; color:#fff;}
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
.size:after{ content: "smartphones portrait";}
body{background-color:#333; color:#fff;}
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
.size:after{ content: "ipad protrait and landscape";}
body{background-color:#444; color:#fff;}
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.size:after{ content: "ipad landscape";}
body{background-color:#555; color:#fff;}
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
.size:after{ content: "iPads portrait";}
body{background-color:#666; color:#000;}
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
.size:after{ content: "desktops and laptops";}
body{background-color:#777; color:#000;}
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
.size:after{ content: "largscreens";}
body{background-color:#888; color:#000;}
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
.size:after{ content: "iPhone 4";}
body{background-color:#999; color:#000;}
}
```

test : www2.iscotest.com/screen.php

Is there just a working standard set for widescreen, desktop (1024), ipad landscape, ipad portrait, mobile portrait and mobile landscape.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use min-width and max-width

Answer (score 1):

Your link is not showing up, did you add the css meta information?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: yeah, that emulator is being sort of uncooperative apparently. Just changing the window size on the actual site www2.iscotest.com/screen.php may be more helpful